# Popper's tooltip.js NuGet package

Tags: asp.net, nuget-package, popper.js

I have downloaded the [popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) NuGet package for some bootstrap features. It works.

Now I want to test and use other their feature - [tooltip.js](https://popper.js.org/tooltip-examples.html).

In the readme.md file is information about instalation of poppers.js throught NuGet but there is no info about the Tooltips.js.
There is no package in NuGet with 'Tooltip.js' name.

How shoud I install and use it in asp.net application correctly?
Does it available at all for .NET (yes I am a newbie)?
May be poppesr's js files already include the code of their tooltip framework?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a NuGet package for you to use it. You can just download the tooltip.js file and reference it on your layout view to use it. Its a client-side library so it doesn't really depend on your server-side tech (.net), just on the browser. NuGet is just a package manager

Comment: But after install the package I have got the 3 files (poppet.js, popper-utils.js, readme.md) (if not count *.min and *.map) in 3 foders (script's root, /umd, /esm) (yes, it is duplicates but I hope this is not a legacy). I am not familiar with correct js destination, order etc in asp.net so I hope that it is right behavior. Shoud I do the same with tooltips.js?